# realm - update object with method createOrUpdateAllFromJson

Tags: android, json, realm

I have an object which has three fields in the json, and one of my own field

```
  public class partner extends RealmObject {
        @PrimaryKey
        @SerializedName("id")
        private int id;

        @SerializedName("name")
        private String name;

        @SerializedName("subtitle")
        private String subtitle;

        private int testInt;
    }
```

This is small example json

```
[{
"id":1,
"name":"test1",
"subtitle":"test2",
}]
```

I save the value in field "testInt", so

```
Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
realm.beginTransaction();
hPartner.setTestInt(6);
realm.commitTransaction();
```

I create/update an object by using code.

```
realm.createOrUpdateAllFromJson(partner.class, new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))));
```

And it all works. 
But value is stored in the field "testInt" is cleared. After the update, I see the value zero. (but must see the value 6)

What should I do to the value in the field "testInt" does not delete?

**UPDATE**
My data is updated every time when application starts.
And I have made the following test (this code is only for test).
This code runs at startup app

```
    realm.beginTransaction();
    realm.createOrUpdateAllFromJson(partner.class, new ByteArrayInputStream(jsonData.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))));
    realm.commitTransaction();

    realm.beginTransaction();
    partner partner = realm.where(partner.class).findFirst();
    partner.setTestInt(6);
    realm.commitTransaction();

    realm.beginTransaction();
    realm.createOrUpdateAllFromJson(partner.class, new ByteArrayInputStream(jsonData.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))));
    realm.commitTransaction();

    partner = realm.where(partner.class).findFirst();
```

In the latter the object "partner" value is stored.And it works!

But if I restarted the application and check the first object "partner" value "testInt" is cleared. Somewhere there is an error or bug.

**UPDATE2**
found the bad code that deletes all records. My mistake
realm.where(partner.class).findAll().deleteAllFromRealm();

Comment: Does `hPartner` have the same primary key with the JSON object? It should keep the same value if you don't have that field in the JSON.

Comment: Yes exactly has the same key!  But unfortunately it removes the value from field "testInt"

Comment: I made some test case to simulate what you described, but everything works as expected. If you can reproduce it with a minimal project, would you please report an issue with the project to https://github.com/realm/realm-java thanks!

Comment: And also, if `hPartner` is a standalone object which means it created by `hPartner = new Partner()`, then I can imagine `testInt` will be "cleared" since it is not stored in the Realm yet.

Comment: Good to know it is solved! And also please note that `realm.where(partner.class).findFirst();` may not always give you the same object since it doesn't have any query conditions.